# Explain the meaning of a matlab code involving filters in binary

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, deep-residual-networks

Hi I have a sample code to convert to python. Unfortunately I am very new to Matlab code. Could you please help me to understand the code. I want to write in python. Any leads would be appreciated. Here the filters are considered in binary. This is a neural network code.

```
%convert the weights to -1 and + 1. Store in single because conv2 requires it

    for i = 1:length(Filters)
        Filters{i} = gpuArray(2*(single(sign(Filters{i}))-0.5));
        NumLearntWeightsEachLayer(i) = size(Filters{i},3)*size(Filters{i},4)*4;
    end
    NumLearntWeightsEachLayer(end) = size(Filters{end},3)*size(Filters{end},4);
    NumLearntWeightsEachLayer
    TotalLearntWeights = sum(NumLearntWeightsEachLayer)
```

Comment: Hi, PRB. "Explain this code" is too broad a question for Stack Overflow. Can you narrow down what you're asking? What do you expect the code to do, and where is its behavior differing from your expectations?

Comment: Hi Andrew , I am a newbie to Matlab. I have this piece of code which needs a translation In Python. I am trying to understand the code myself. I think the code is iterating through the length of the filter over an unsigned value of the filter. I would like to know the equivalent code for this in Python.